# nth-everything css Почему не вработает?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Вот код     http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx тут все работает. Копирую к себе все тоже самое, подключаю такую же версию jquery-2.1.4.js и никакой реакции, что я делаю не так?

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nthEverything.js" ></script>
```

Вот ссылка на мой код http://rghost.ru/7t4Wr7pFT

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Не стоит размещать код где-то и давать ссылки – со временем они ломаются. Вместо этого размещайте прямо в вопросе фрагменты кода, достаточные для воспроизведения проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынеси подключение скриптов в конец body и замени подключаемый стиль, встроенным в страницу.

Comment: Чудеса) Спасибо большое, все получилось)

Comment: @l2banners: если ответ помог вам решить задачу, вы можете отметить его как верный с помощью галочки слева от ответа.